# Functor application over division

Tags: haskell, functor

My question can be written in the context of lists. I have a function doing what is analogous to:

```hs
div' xs n = (*) (1 / n) <$> xs
```

Can this be simplified at all? I have been unable to work anything out.

Comment: ``(`div` n) <$> xs``?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ah! I needed `(/ n) <$> xs` (I should have mentioned I needed fractional). Thanks for the help! I tried  `((/) n) <$> xs`, but your comment explains why I was mistaken!

Comment: Even if you don't know about sections, you should be able to go simpler: `(\x -> x/n) <$> xs`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah, that is arguably simpler. I was trying to find a way to what is the current accepted answer, and I simply get stuck where my question begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the [*section of an infix operator* <sup>[Haskell-wiki]</sup>](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) and write `(/ n)` to construct a function that will divide by `n`, that means you can implement `div'` as:

```
div' :: (Functor f, Fractional a) => f a -> a -> f a
div' xs n = (/ n) <$> xs
```